ElGamal in openPGP
Is there a reason that OpenPGP chose to use Elgamal for symmetric key exchange? Couldn't it have just used DH which is based on the same maths but is much simpler?

So I (think) have found the answer to my own question. The reason PGP chose ElGamal over regular DH is because at the time PGP was conceived (1991), DH was under a US patent (patent issued in 1977 and expired in 1997) while ElGamal is available under public domain. This is quite funny in its own right since ElGamal pretty much has to use DH to derive the shared secret for encryption.
